# How to make highcharts-ng horizontal bar chart responsive

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have worked with several type of highcharts-ng, and the horizontal bar chart seems to be special - I had hard time to make the chart width adapt to the screen size. To illustrate the problem, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miliu99/46rhz/698/). By default, it has a fixed size of 600px, instead of the whole available width. I tried various ways to adjust the width accordingly, but none of them works perfectly. One way is to use $window.onresize as shown in the code, but it doesn't work. However, if I put a Resize button which runs the same code, it does work. Why?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <input ng-model="chart.title.text">
    <button ng-click="resize()">Resize</button>
    <highchart id="chart1" series="chart.series" title="chart.title" options="chart.options"></highchart>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $window) {

  $scope.resize = function() {
    $scope.chart.options.chart.width = $window.innerWidth;
  }
  $window.onresize = function() {
    $scope.chart.options.chart.width = $window.innerWidth;
  }

  $scope.chart = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Hello'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `window.onresize` refers to the global window object which does not have the chart config object in opposite to `$scope.toggleWidth` in which `this` refers to the scope with the chart.

Chart config can be accessed like this:

```
$window.onresize = function () {
  var chart = $scope.chart.options.chart;
  if (chart.width === 400) {
        chart.width = 800
    } else {
        chart.width = 400
    }
  $scope.$digest();
};
```

onresize you need to manually call `$digest()`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wscqtdvo/

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip of $digest() call. Strange, this works as long as I use it in a controller. However, when I put it into a directive, it stops working. I tried to create another jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/miliu99/vzk1533y/, but I couldn't make it run in jsfiddle at all. However, it does contain the basic structure of my directive, and I hope you can give me another tip to resolve this issue.